# Shiny Document: how to center align output of RenderPlot

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, document

I am creating a Shiny Document in R and want the plot generated with Shiny RenderPlot to be centered, or right, or height = 50%. However, the fig.align=center or right or out-width = "50%" in the r chunk does not affect the output (I suppose it is for figures generated directly in R, not via Shiny). How to center?

Try to change out.width, or fig.align, and it won't change a thing.

````
--
title: "Untitled"
author: "Gahis"
date: "8/4/2021"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE, fig.align='right', out.width="50%"}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),
  
  sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
              min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
)

renderPlot({
  hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
       xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")
  
  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
})
```
````

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a full, minimal example? That would help.

Comment: Sure thing. I have reedited the question. Thanks!

Comment: This is not *full*. Please include the file header, etc.

Comment: Apologies. Now it should be correct.

Comment: So you want to reduce the width of the plot? Because by default the width is 100% and the plot is centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can reduce the width of the plot and centering it. Add this CSS:

```
<style>
.center50 { 
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
</style>
```

Then include you `renderPlot` in a `div` with the class `center50`:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

<style>
.center50 { 
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
</style>

```{r}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),
  
  sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
              min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
)
```

```{r}
div(class = "center50",
    
    renderPlot({
      hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
           xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")
      dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
      lines(dens, col = "blue")
    })
    
)
```
````

Comment: Fabulous, thank you! Is it possible to add it in a css r chunk like so: ```{css, echo=FALSE} .center50y {...} instead of using <style>? Also, to indicate the alignment what shall I use in the css chunk?

Comment: @Adel I didn't try but that sounds possible. For left-alignment, simply remove `margin: auto`.

Comment: @Adel Type "html align div right" on Google, you will find.

Comment: One more thing: strange behaviour. Do I need to close the div? If I write some markdown after that r chunk, it is hidden by the plot.

Comment: @Adel Sorry i don't see what you mean. I've tried to write "Hello" after this chunk and it works. What did you do?

Comment: I have created a new post, maybe you can help again? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68663121/how-to-adjust-div-containing-plotly-to-plot-dimensions-so-it-does-not-overlap-do