# How to adjust div containing plotly to plot dimensions so it does not overlap document

Tags: html, r, plotly, r-markdown, r-plotly

I am using plotly to produce a plot in RMarkdown.
However, as it is embedded in a div, it overlaps with the following text.
I think it's because of a conflict between the plotly size and div.

````
  ---
    title: "TITLE"
    author: "AUTHOR"
    date: "1/1/2000"
    output:
      html_document
    ---
    
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(
      warning = FALSE,
      message = FALSE,
      echo = FALSE  # show R code
    )
    
    ```
    ## scatter 1
    
    ```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE,out.width="100%",out.height="100%",fig.align='center'}
    library(plotly)
    library(htmltools)
    mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 0)] <- 'Automatic'
    mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 1)] <- 'Manual'
    mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
    
    fig <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~hp, z = ~qsec, color = ~am, colors = c('#BF382A', '#0C4B8E'))
    fig <- fig %>% add_markers()
    fig <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Weight'),
                         yaxis = list(title = 'Gross horsepower'),
                         zaxis = list(title = '1/4 mile time')))
    
    
    fig %>% layout(autosize = F, width = 1000, height = 800,paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)', margin = list(r = 10,t = 25,b = 40,l = 110)) -> p
    
    div(p,align='center')
    ```
# HEADING
    
asdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasda
````

[image]

As you see the text is hidden. How to tweak the div properties to make it visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `out.height="100%"` from the chunk options.

Also, set the width and the height in the `plotly` function, not in `layout`.

````
---
title: "TITLE"
author: "AUTHOR"
date: "1/1/2000"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
warning = FALSE,
message = FALSE,
echo = FALSE  # show R code
)

```
## scatter 1

```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE, out.width="100%", fig.align='center'}
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)
mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 0)] <- 'Automatic'
mtcars$am[which(mtcars$am == 1)] <- 'Manual'
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)

fig <- plot_ly(
    mtcars,
    x = ~ wt,
    y = ~ hp,
    z = ~ qsec,
    color = ~ am,
    colors = c('#BF382A', '#0C4B8E'),
    width = 1000,
    height = 800
  )
fig <- fig %>% add_markers()
fig <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Weight'),
yaxis = list(title = 'Gross horsepower'),
zaxis = list(title = '1/4 mile time')))


fig %>% layout(
  autosize = F,
  paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)',
  margin = list(
    r = 10,
    t = 25,
    b = 40,
    l = 110
  )
) -> p

div(p, align='center')
```

# HEADING

asdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasdasdas asdasdasdasda
````

Comment: Thanks, was changing too many variables at the same time!